# Set origin on d3 graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm messing around with d3 but a basic line seems to be inverted. Seems like the origin is at the top of the page (like the default orientation on a page). However, i assumed that the d3 points were relative to the svg graph.

How can I set the origin to be bottom left of graph? (Without transforming the data)
[image]

```
// make dataset
var dataset = [[1,1]];
for (var x = 0; x< 10000; x +=1) {
    var y = x*x;
    dataset.push([x, y])
}

// set graph dims
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");;



// add scale
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 200]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1000]).range([height, 0]);


// add x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(10);

// add y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(10);

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

//add dots
svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d[0];
   })
   .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d[1];
   })
   .attr("r", 1);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the orientation: it has nothing to do with D3. D3 manipulates DOM elements, and normally (but not always) we use D3 to manipulate SVG elements. And the SVG specs say that the origin (0,0) is at the top left corner.

Regarding your problem: you correctly set the y scale to go from the bottom to the top, but you simply forgot to use it! Use the scale:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d[0]);
})
.attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
// make dataset
var dataset = [[1,1]];
for (var x = 0; x< 100; x +=1) {
    var y = x*x;
    dataset.push([x, y])
}

// set graph dims
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");;



// add scale
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 200]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1000]).range([height - margin.bottom - margin.top, 0]);


// add x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(10);

// add y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(10);

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

//add dots
svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d[0]);
   })
   .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
   })
   .attr("r", 1);
```

```css
line, path {
 fill: none;
 stroke: black;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```